# pygame.draw.rect TypeError: Rect argument is invalid

Tags: python, pygame, typeerror

I'm writing an Jump'n'Run for fun with Python 3 and Pygame right now.
This time I'm trying to make a 'button'-class out of my old function to make the game better readable and to get better performances for it.
This is my old code:

```
    def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action=None):
        time.sleep(0)
        mouse=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,black,(x,y,w,h),2)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, ac,(x,y,w,h))
            noevent = False
            if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
                    action()
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,black,(x,y,w,h),4)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, ic,(x,y,w,h))
        textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
        textRect.center = ( (x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)) )
        screen.blit(textSurf, textRect)
```

Now I started writing a class out of it:

```
    class buttons():
    def __init__(self,sort,msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action=None):
            self.type=sort
            self.msg=msg
            self.x=x
            self.y=y
            self.w=w
            self.h=h
            self.ic=ic
            self.ac=ac
            self.action=action
            self.mouse=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            self.click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
            self.noevent = False
    def render(self):
            if self.x+self.w > self.mouse[0] > self.x and self.y+self.h > self.mouse[1] > self.y:
                    pygame.draw.rect(screen,black,(self.x,self.y,self.w,self.h),2)
                    pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.ac,(self.x,self.y,self.w,self.h))
                    if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
                            self.action()
            else:
                    pygame.draw.rect(screen,black,(self.x,self.y,self.w,self.h),4)
                    pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.ic,(self.x,self.y,self.w,self.h))
            self.textSurf, self.textRect = text_objects(self.msg, smallText)
            self.textRect.center = ( (self.x+int(self.w/2)), (self.y+int(self.h/2)))
            screen.blit(self.textSurf, self.textRect)
```

But it gave me the same Issue:

```
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,black,(self.x,self.y,self.w,self.h),4)
        TypeError: Rect argument is invalid
```

I don't now what to do. I also read the other questions to this theme on Stackoverflow. I can't get the problem.

Comment: `pygame.draw.rect` takes a `Rect` object, not a tuple.  Try `pygame.draw.rect(screen,black, Rect(self.x,self.y,self.w,self.h),4)
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pygame.draw.rect()` expects `pygame.Rect()` object not tuple `(x, y, w, h)`

So keep size and position as `pygame.Rect()`

```
self.rect = pygame.Rect()
self.rect.x = x
self.rect.y = y
self.rect.width = w
self.rect.height = h
```

or shorter

```
self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, w, h)
```

and you will no need all this `self.x` , `self.y`, etc.

```
pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, self.rect, 4)

screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

---

You can check mouse over button

```
if self.rect.collidepoint(self.mouse):
```

instead of

```
if self.x+self.w > self.mouse[0] > self.x and self.y+self.h > self.mouse[1] > self.y:
```

---

You can also use

- `self.rect.right` instead of `self.x+self.w`
- `self.rect.bottom` instead of `self.y+self.h`
- `self.rect.centerx` instead of `self.x+(self.w/2)`
- `self.rect.centery` instead of `self.y+(selfh./2)`
- etc.

---

You can center text on button

```
self.textRect.center = self.rect.center
```

instead of

```
self.textRect.center = ( (self.x+int(self.w/2)), (self.y+int(self.h/2)) )
```

See PyGame doc: [pygame.Rect()](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html)

---

**BTW:** [example of button code](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/pygame/button-hover)

---

**BTW:** to make code more readable use `CamelCase` names for classes `class Button` and `lower_case` names for functions/methods and variables `self.text_image`, `self.text_rect`

See: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Thanks for you time on my question, but 'self.rect = pygame.Rect()' causes me another error:     'self.rect = pygame.Rect()
TypeError: Argument must be rect style object'

Comment: it may need arguments - try directly `pygame.Rect(x,y,w,h)` - you have link to doc so you can check it.